# "In England it isn’t so cold as in Russia." vs "England isn’t so cold as Russia." vs "It's not so cold in England as it is in Russia."

Tags: comparative-constructions

> **In England it isn’t so cold as in Russia.**
>
> England isn’t so cold as Russia.
>
> **It's not so cold in England as it is in Russia.**

Are all of the sentences fine? As I understand it, the third version is the best one from the point of view of English grammar. Is it possible to use some shorter versions? It seems to me that the second version is awkward, or it has a double meaning.

Comment: The first version is "weird", but I can't see the point in trying to figure out whether it's "ungrammatical" or just "non-idiomatic". The other two are both fine - use whichever you like.

Comment: I think there is a word missing from the first one.  Did you mean "In England it isn't so cold as in Russia" ?

Comment: If you want it shorter, try stating it the other way round:  "Russia is colder than England".

Comment: @Thruston: Precisely my point! I don't think there's anything to be gained by attempting to draw a line between ***with** dummy "**it**"* (unquestionably "valid") and ***without** dummy "**it**"* (opinions may vary, and it seems unlikely there will be a relevant formally-defined "rule" for this exact context).

Comment: @Thruston, I want to use the turn of phrase: "so ... as" to express that idea.

Comment: Does **"In England it isn't so cold as in Russia"** sound good?

Comment: The second sentence is the shortest version using "*so ... as*". A shorter sentence with the same meaning is: "*Russia is colder than England.*"

Comment: There seem to me no reasons whatever to object to any of them from a grammatical or idiomacy point of view - and this applies to the first one too.

Comment: Please change the first and third example sentences in the title; they don't currently match the first and third example sentences in the body.

Comment: Perhaps also: "England isn't **as** cold as Russia", see https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13707/14014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three sentences are good grammar, and have almost identical meaning.

The 1st and 3rd sentences are identical in meaning, and refer only to the air temperature. Without any context, the 2nd sentence also has that meaning, but in the right context, it *could* mean that Russian *people* or some subset of them, like the government, are colder than their English counterparts in one or both of the following senses:

> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cold):
> **cold**
> **2 a :** marked by a lack of the warmth of normal human emotion, friendliness, or compassion
> **b :** not colored or affected by personal feeling or bias : detached, indifferent

Comment: To my mind that could almost certainly apply to any of them.